# MVP or MVC - Which one allows to write loosely coupled code?

Tags: model-view-controller, webforms, mvp

Though I have gone through some articles regarding MVC and MVP, I am not able to take decision to write code with MVP or MVC pattern?

Which pattern will allow us to write loosely coupled code? Can I assume Asp.Net web forms is MVP by default?

Answer (score 3):

Both patterns allow you to write loosely coupled code. Out of the box ASP.NET WebForms is not MVP. You need to [make it](http://webformsmvp.com/). There's even a [framework](http://aspnetmvp.codeplex.com/) which may simplify this task.

Answer (score 0):

Neither. Both. Patterns might help, but its you who writes either tightly or loosely coupled code in the end.